# Flip toggle switch looking rectangular instead of round

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, jquery-mobile

I create a flip toggle switch with jQuery mobile like this:

```
<div>         
  <select name ="oeffDienst" id="oeffDienst" data-role="slider">
    <option value="0">Nein</option>
    <option value="1">Ja</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and it should look like this:

[image: Correct format]

but instead it looks like this:

[image: Wrong style]

I am using jQuery mobile 1.3.2, which is supposed to have [these flip toggle switches](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/sliders/switch.html). I tested it on Android, iOS and Mac, all looking the same (wrong) way.

Anyone knows what is happening here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle which replicate your issue?

Comment: Seems like you have some other CSS meddling with the standard jQuery Mobile CSS. Works fine here: http://jsbin.com/EpUYUked/1/

Comment: It seems you're using JQM 1.4 style sheet not 1.3.2 check this http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-rc.1/dist/demos/slider-flipswitch/

Comment: Nope, I'm using 1.3.2. Is there maybe a fallback or something?

Comment: found the problem, a designer sent me a scheme that was transforming the toggle buttons (made with the jQM theme roller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem, I was using a scheme that was transforming the toggle buttons 
(made with the [jQM theme roller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/))